# Is this the place to ask about personal tax report questions?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if this site is the right place to ask about personal tax report questions?

If no, where can I ask such questions?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that it is.

Be sure to provide details like the applicable jurisdiction.  (i.e. country, state/province)